# Is there a way to encapsulate a 2nd class into primary class?

Tags: c#, encapsulation, inner-classes

I'm wondering how to have primary class show objects of 2nd class (keep 2nd class internal)?  I'm using c#.

Sort of like a wrapper.  Is that a bad thing?  Can somebody provide an example or links?

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "show objects of 2nd class"?

Comment: You can use an inner class.

Comment: Inner class/Decorator Pattern/Inheritance.... I think you need to be more specific as to your problem...

Comment: 1) "show objects of 2nd class" - think of this as abstract, interface, etc.  2) "inner class" - Hmm..  That could work but I'm not sure it would help if I have like 100 classes for example.   3) "Inner class/decorator pattern/inheritance" - I'm looking for something where I don't have to add ":" to a primary class for every classes

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Please be a bit more verbose. *You* know what you mean, but *we* don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple pattern for this would be to use a nested class, with properties to expose what you want to make public.

```
public class MyClass
{
   private class SubClass
   {
      int someValue;
   }

   private SubClass innerClass = new SubClass();

   public int SubValue
   {
      get { return innerClass.someValue; }
      set { innerClass.someValue = value; }
   }
}
```

You can scale out this pattern to have, effectively, many private sub classes by using the [internal modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Internal objects are essentially public to code within the same assembly, and private everywhere else. Mark the wrapper as public and each child as internal. Note that this requires putting the wrapper class and all child classes in their own separate project (i.e., assembly). You can (and should) have each class defined in its own file within the new project.

```
public class WrapperClass
{
   private SubClass1 internalClass1 = new internalClass1();
   private SubClass2 internalClass2 = new internalClass2();

   public int SubValue1
   {
      get { return internalClass1.someValue; }
      set { internalClass1.someValue = value; }
   }

   public int SubValue2
   {
      get { return internalClass2.someValue; }
      set { internalClass2.someValue = value; }
   }
}

internal class SubClass1
{
   int someValue;
}

internal class SubClass2
{
   int someValue;
}
```

Comment: That could work but i'm afraid it will cause performance or overhead if I have 100 classes.  So suggestion??

Comment: @fletchsod I don't quite understand. Do you mean you have 100 inner classes that you want to host within one big public wrapper class? Or that you have 100 pairs of wrapper / sub classes and just don't want to spend time coding the nesting pattern?

Comment: Yea, 100 seperate classes (seperate files0 to be wrapped around by 1 public wrapper class.

Comment: @fletchsod - Move all those classes to their own project and mark them as internal, then create your single public wrapper class. See my updated answer.